# Restrict access to page with session_start()

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working on a login page who if you login you're redirected to a upload page and i'm trying to restrict access to the upload page if you are not logged in and i don't want people to have access tot he page if they are not loggin.
So far this is my code but i don't know how to restrict access with session's.
my login script:

```
<?php
    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="root"; // Mysql username 
    $password=""; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="ana"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name="user"; // Table name 

    // Connect to server and select databse.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    // username and password sent from form 
    $myusername=$_POST['user']; 
    $mypassword=$_POST['pass']; 

    // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE user='$myusername' and pass='$mypassword'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);


    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($myusername=='ana' and $mypassword==''){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["myusername"]=$myusername;
    $_SESSION["mypassword"]=$mypassword; 
    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
    echo "Your login was succesfull!";  
    header("refresh:3;url=upload.php");
    }
    else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password, please try again.";
    header("refresh:3;url=connect.php");
    }

?>
```

and the page that redirects you to it is :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
    Astral by HTML5 UP
    html5up.net | @n33co
    Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
-->
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ana Gemescu - Work work work | Upload </title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/init.js"></script>
        <noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel.css" />
        </noscript>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Wrapper-->
            <div id="wrapper">

                <!-- Main -->
                    <div id="main">
                        <!-- Me -->
                            <article id="me" class="panel">
                                <header>
                                <form action="uploader.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    Select image to upload:<br />
                                    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br />
                                    <select name="Folder" style="width:500px;margin-bottom:5px;margin-top:5px;" >
                                            <option value="photo" style="padding:2px">Photos</option>
                                            <option value="draw" style="padding:2px">Drawings</option>
                                            <option value="video" style="padding:2px">Videos</option>
                                            <option value="other" style="padding:2px">Other</option>
                                    </select><br />
                                    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
                                </form>
                                </header>
                            </article>
                        </div>
                <!-- Footer -->
                    <div id="footer">
                        <ul class="copyright">
                            <li>&copy; Ana Gemescu</li><li>Design: <a href="http://html5up.net">HTML5 UP</a>, Coded by: <a href="#">zapo</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Can please some one help me how do i restrict access to the upload page if your not logged in ?

If you need more information please let me know

Comment: Sidenote: You're outputting before header in *and the page that redirects you to it is*. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields such a warning, which most likely will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the `$_SESSION["myusername"]`, like this

```
if(ISSET($_SESSION["myusername"]))
{
    //upload page code
}
else
{
    print "access denied";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Start by calling the `session_start();` method on each page you need to use it. You can avoid this by calling this method once in a baseclass which sets up your mySQL connection, of course each class that inherits the connection settings will inherit the session_start() method.

As for your authenticity check, consider the below example:

```
//Create a new session object that will determine when a user is authenticated. 
$_SESSION['isAuthenticated'] = false;
```

You could possibly initialise this in the class which is called when the user successfully logs in, in that case the boolean value would switch to true on successful login.

```
//Your welcome page, after log-in
if( isset($_SESSION['isAuthenticated']) )
{
    $_SESSION['isAuthenticated'] = true
}
```

On each new page you could then create a condition which checks if the value is set to true (user is authenticated)

```
if( !isset($_SESSION['isAuthenticated']) || $_SESSION['isAuthenticated'] == false)
{
  echo "You are not authenticated to view this page, please log-in";
}
else
{
   //start your HTML here
}
```

This rules out someone simply typing the page url into the address bar and bypassing your login logic.

Answer (score 1):

Always put `session_start();` at the top of your page... before any output.

Verifying whether a session variable has been set is simply:

```
session_start(); //at the very top of your page
if(!isset($_SESSION['your_index'])){ //for example user
   //do something
   //for example, send the user back to the login page

   header('Location: myloginform.php'); //path to where your login form is located. Headers need to be above any output or they will produce an error and thus not work as intended (or at all even!)
   exit;
   }
```

Also make sure that you take appropriate security measures in consideration for the script that does the actual uploading of the file.
For example...

- Verifying file type being uploaded, you surely don't want to let a user upload anything he/she desires to your server
- Correct permissions at your upload folder (e.g. full permissions 777 is just asking for problems)

Answer (score 0):

When a user logs in to the system, then store a flag in a session e.g. $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;  read out the value each call. If $_SESSION['loggedin'] == 1 then user is safe.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help! I've manage to made it with session_start();. 
Keep up the good work guys and thanks again.